# Stale GORM Session Causes Spock Unit Test to Fail

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spock

I'm upgrading an existing application from Grails 2.4.4 to Grails 4.0.10 and I'm trying to test the logout code that works in the Grails 2.4.4 app now.  However, when I call `findAllByUsername` after deleting all the tokens for that user, GORM returns apparently stale data.

To test this, I tried
`AuthenticationToken.list().find { it.username == username }`, and it returns `null`.  However, `AuthenticationToken.findAllByUsername(username)` returns the 3 records that were just deleted.

How can I prevent `findAllByUsername` from returning stale data in this unit test?

```
package us.cloudcard.api

import grails.testing.gorm.DataTest
import grails.testing.gorm.DomainUnitTest
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import spock.lang.Specification

class AuthenticationTokenSpec extends Specification implements DomainUnitTest<AuthenticationToken>, DataTest {

    def setup() {
        [AuthenticationToken, Photo, Person].each { mockDomain(it) }
    }

    def "test logout"() {
        setup:
        String username = "bacon"
        [username, "eggs", "biscuits", "gravy", username, "hashbrowns", username].each {
            new AuthenticationToken(username: it).save(validate: false) 
        }

        when:
        List<AuthenticationToken> tokensForUser = AuthenticationToken.findAllByUsername(username)
        AuthenticationToken.deleteAll(tokensForUser, flush: true)

        then:
        AuthenticationToken.list().find { it.username == username } == null // this passes
        AuthenticationToken.findAllByUsername(username).empty // this fails
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but FYI... `DomainUnitTest` implements `DataTest` so I don't think there is any reason for your test to implement both.  You should be able to implement just `DomainUnitTest`.

Comment: Instead of `[AuthenticationToken, Photo, Person].each { mockDomain(it) }` you could call `mockDomains AuthenticationToken, Photo, Person`.